# Python3 Class Syntax Error: non-default argument follows default argument

Tags: python-3.x

I'm messing around with Class' and I have a python3 file with the following code:

```
class playerstats(object):
def __init__(self, name, baselevel=1, hp, mana, basedmg=0, atkdmg, basedef=0, chardef):
    self.name = name
    self.baselevel = baselevel
    self.hp = hp
    self.mana = mana
    self.basedmg = basedmg
    self.atkdmg = atkdmg
    self.basedef = basedef
    self.chardef = chardef
    return self.name, self.baselevel, self.basedmg, self.basedef
def selectedclass(self, chosenclass):
    if chosenclass == 'W' or chosenclass == 'w':
        self.hp = 100
        self.mana = 50
    elif chosenclass == 'M' or chosenclass == 'm':
        self.hp = 75
        self.mana = 100
    else:
        print('Error')
    return self.hp, self.mana

charcreation = playerstats('Tom', baselevel, self.chosenclass, self.chosenclass, basedmg, 0, basedef, 0)

self.chosenclass = 'w'

print(playerstats.hp)
```

When I run it, I get this Error:
File "..\Playground\", line 2
    def **init**(self, name, baselevel=1, hp, mana, basedmg=0, atkdmg, basedef=0, chardef):
                 ^
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument

Can someone help me understand why?

Answer (score 8):

You need to change the order of parameters in `__init__` function.

Generally, non-default argument should not follow default argument , it means you can't define `(a="b",c)` in function.

The order of defining parameter in function are :

- positional parameter or non-default parameter i.e (a,b,c)
- keyword parameter or default parameter i.e (a="bcd",r="jef")
- keyword-only parameter i.e (*args)
- var-keyword parameter i.e (**kwargs)

Comment: @esteel: You need any more information or clarification ?

Comment: @esteel: Have you tested with above changes ?

Comment: I have and it worked but I got another error after that. Will post when I get home